# Determining Probability of Multiple Dies with Similar Faces

Tags: combinatorics

I have the case where I know what to do with normal equally fair dice, especially in succession, but I have a situation where I have many dice that have varying numbers of similar faces, and I'm trying to find the probability of a single event.

The premise is there are 16 dice with letters, some with multiple identical faces, and I need to determine the probability of a single event between all of them. Here is a sample set for some examples:

```
    {A, A, E, E, G, N}, {E, L, R, T, T, Y}, {A, O, O, T, T, W}, {A, B, B, J, O, O}, 

    {E, H, R, T, V, W}, {C, I, M, O, T, U}, {D, I, S, T, T, Y}, {E, I, O, S, S, T}, 

    {D, E, L, R, V, Y}, {A, C, H, O, P, S}, {H, I, M, N, Qu, U}, {E, E, I, N, S, U},

    {E, E, G, H, N, W}, {A, F, F, K, P, S},{H, L, N, N, R, Z}, {D, E, I, L, R, X}
```

What would be the probability of at least 1 of a given letter? Let's say A for example. In this case I would think that we would multiply the $\frac{x}{6}$ probability of landing on that letter across each of the 16 dices, which in case for A would be:

$\frac{2}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$
$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$
$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{0}{0}$$\frac{0}{6}$
$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$$\frac{0}{6}$

But that leaves multiple zero probabilities and we can't go multiplying by zero, so I'd believe that we simply ignore the dice that have zero probability in that case and only focus on the dice that have a non-zero probability, since these should also be independent events. That would be:

$\frac{2}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$$\frac{1}{6}$ = 0.0257%

But that causes an obvious problem. We're trying to find the likelihood that A will show up **at least once** across all 16 dies, so the fact that it is present across multiple dies would mean it has to be greater than at least $\frac{1}{6}$ right?

I know that if you roll a fair 6-numbered die that if you try to get the same result twice, your chances are $\frac{1}{6}$*$\frac{1}{6}$=$\frac{1}{36}$, but is the exact same situation applying here?

For another example, what would be the possibility of "Qu" showing up when rolling all 16 dice? I believe it'd just be $\frac{1}{6}$ since only 1 die has "Qu" and is independent of all the other dice. Since it only shows up once on that die then the probability of "Qu" showing up at least once when rolling all the dice should be $\frac{1}{6}$ right?

Comment: To get the probability that at least one instance of a thing is observed, it is frequently easier to compute the probability that no instances of the thing are observed.

Comment: There is confusion about what you are asking.  In your **worked example**, the product represented the probability that $A$ showed on each of the dice.  The zero probability reflected that this is impossible because some of the dice don't have an $A$.  So, you have to **first** clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @user2661923 I guess that shows the fault in my logic I was looking for. So if the way I tried calculating in the example would give the result for "A" showing up on every die, which is not what I was trying to compute, what would be the proper way to determine "A" showing up at least once on any die? Would the method be additive instead of multiplicative? since with every die with an "A" face the chance of the event would be higher?

Comment: If the probability of A **not** showing on Die-k is $f(k)$, and there are $(r)$ dice, then the probability that at least one of the $(r)$ dice shows an A is $$1 - \left[\prod_{k=1}^r f(k)\right].$$

Comment: @user2661923 excuse me for my ignorance, but what is that function? I know summation but I'm not familiar with that "uppercase pi" looking symbol. Does it have a name?

Comment: The $~\displaystyle \prod ~$ function represents the product of all of the factors.  So the expression can be equivalently expressed as $$1 - \left[f(1) \times f(2) \times \cdots \times f(r)\right].$$

Comment: Grammar tip:  The noun die is irregular.  Its plural is dice.  The word dies is the third person singular form of the verb to die.